# Get request that can take any amount of params passed from the front-end

Tags: express

I'm trying to make the server dynamic enough to be able to accept any amount of params I pass from the front-end.

Here is the backend code:

```
app.get(['/api/sc/:something', '/sc/:something', '/api/sc/:something/:serviceParams'], async (req, res) => {
  const service = req.params.service;
  // get the token from the header
  const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  const service_ = ((service, serviceParams) => {
    if(serviceParams === undefined){
      return service;
    }
    return service + "/" + serviceParams
  })(req.params.service, req.params.serviceParams)
  // add the token to the bearer header of axiosInstance and then call the api
  const options = getOptions(service_, token, "GET");
  try {
    const a = await axiosInstance(options);
    res.json(a.data)
  } catch (d) {
    if ([202, 302, 303].indexOf(d.response.status) !== -1) {
      // response is not ready yet, so do a get loop
      res.send(await getLoop(d.response.data.location, token));
    } else {
      res.json({error: d.response.data})
    }
  }
});
```

My goal is that if I make a request from the front-end that looks like this:

```
 try {
      const historyRes = await apiClient.get("/api/sc/something/match/history");
      setHistoryData(historyRes.data)
      console.log(historyRes, "HISTORY")
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error)
      }
```

This fails, but as I've compensated in the code above, something like `get("/api/sc/something/history")` will work fine. Is there a way I can make the backend dynamic enough to accept any amount of params I send, without having to tack on more and more values to the array I'm passing in?

```
app.get(['/api/sc/:something', '/sc/:something'], async (req, res) => {
  const service = req.params.service;
  // get the token from the header
  const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  
  })(req.params.service, req.params.serviceParams)
  // add the token to the bearer header of axiosInstance and then call the api
  const options = getOptions(service, token, "GET");
  try {
    const a = await axiosInstance(options);
    res.json(a.data)
  } catch (d) {
    if ([202, 302, 303].indexOf(d.response.status) !== -1) {
      // response is not ready yet, so do a get loop
      res.send(await getLoop(d.response.data.location, token));
    } else {
      res.json({error: d.response.data})
    }
  }
});
```

This was my original try to see if this will accept values I pass through from the front-end to kind of work as a "wildcard", but it doesn't seem to have the desired effect.

Comment: `/api/sc/*`? But it might be better to use something other than path params (e.g. search/query params, or a request body if you use a non-GET request).

Comment: Great this actually worked fine for me :) I have set it to use /api/sc/* and then for my check I just do service= req.params[0]